# How to format Python MySQLdb SELECT result into json.dumps, key-value pairs to be present in json object

Tags: python, json, select, mysql-python

Please give an example, I am finding it difficult to have the Mysql db result to make it as jsonobject.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include the code you've tried and whatever makes it unsuitable. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cur.execute('select title, text from posts order by id desc')
posts = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
```

Now you should get python list(dictionary).You can appl this in your database.

Hope this will help for you

Comment: Thanks for your response, Is there a better way of doing , Because my select query returns 22 column results, should I assign by hard coding the column names all the time, The above example is for 2 columns ...                                                                                                        I Eg: json => {{"name":"foo", "floor":"2", "section":"2A", .......so on 22 columns}}

Comment: if you want all columns, use `select * from `

Comment: otherwise create a list of columns by `col_list = json.keys()` and `q=" ".join(col_list)` then `cur.execute('select '+q+' from posts order by id desc')`